# How to know which Entry has been clicked?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a program that creates entry widgets using a for loop:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
entList = []

def deleteChar(event):
    ent.delete(0, 'end')
    ent.insert(0, '')
    ent.config(fg='black')

for x in range(12):
    ent = Entry(root, fg='grey60')
    ent.insert(0, 'Enter Name')
    ent.pack()
    ent.bind('<FocusIn>', deleteChar)
    entList.append(ent)
    root.mainloop()
```

Is there any way to make the function recognize which entry has been clicked so it will delete the text in that one instead of only the last one created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly one widget in an application will have keyboard focus. You can query for which widget has the focus. In addition, the `event` object that is passed in has a reference to the widget that triggered the callback, which is typically what you do in an event callback.

```
def deleteChar(event):
    event.widget.delete(0, 'end')
    event.widget.insert(0, '')
    event.widget.config(fg='black')
```